# numpy array not recognizing column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I tried to create a function to call the model I had built, but when running the function, I got an error:'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
please I need your assistance, below is the function and the error message

def predit_price(location, sqft, bath, bhk):
global x
loc_index = np.where(x.columns==location)[0][0]

```
x = np.zeros(len(x.columns))


x[0] =sqft
x[1] =  bath
x[2] = bhk
if loc_index >=0:
    x[loc_index] =1
    
return lm.predict([x])[0]
```

predit_price('1st Phase JP Nagar', 1000, 3, 2)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 predit_price('1st Phase JP Nagar', 1000, 3, 2)

in predit_price(location, sqft, bath, bhk)
1 def predit_price(location, sqft, bath, bhk):
2     global x
----> 3     loc_index = np.where(x.columns==location)[0][0]
4
5     x = np.zeros(len(x.columns))

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: if `x` is a numpy array, then it doesn't have a `columns` attribute. Did you mean to use a pandas dataframe? Or array slicing or x.shape[1]`?

Comment: what is `x.columns` supposed to?  What is `x` supposed to be?

Comment: x is a DataFrame. The Independent variables. x.columns return all the columns in x